# When should Asp.net MVC views be unit tested

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, view

Suppose you have a project with many developers working on the same Asp.net MVC application. Project is a long run one, so team members will change over time. This means that during this time we get to a point where certain views seem (totally) different to others. Markup wise.

In order to keep the UI as consistent as possible over time let's say that initial team develops a sort of fluent Html helper methods, for creating generic view structure. Ie:

```
Html.CreateHeader("Header text")
    .CreateForm(Url.Action(...))
    .AddSegment("Person")
    .EditorFor(model => model.Person)
    .AddSegment("...")
    .EditorFor(model => model.Company)
    ...
```

Although this does add an additional abstraction over everyday Asp.net MVC view code, but it makes views consistent over time. Of course when these fluent helpers are used.

**But**. Even though each of these helper methods can be unit tested I wonder what good it is to test views themselves?

### Questions

1. My opinion is that you don't unit test anything static (ie. views). So unless views have rich client side functionality, nothing should be tested. But if it does, you would be testing Javascript code with ie. QUnit library. Is this thinking correct or does it really make sense to test something that is intrinsically static in nature and we'd only be testing presence of certain elements and their content?
2. What other aspects of views can be tested and why should they be tested?

> During my development I've noticed that unit testing should only be done on non-trivial code. In other words methods that have at least one branch should be tested, and others that are long enough to not be completely obvious what they do even without branches.
>
> I tend to avoid writing unit tests for methods that are trivial in nature, because they don't aid anything except consuming developer's time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views should only be presenting the data that is provided to them, therefore there shouldn't be any logic to test anyway.

In my opinion the "testing" of views comes under integration testing. (Checking everything looks ok, links go to the right places etc.)

Comment: Exactly my point. And they should be tested using tools like WatinN or Selenium and not code tests as unit tests usually are written. Well integration tests are mainly written that way as well. Up to the point of views that would be.

Comment: Agree. WatiN (or alternative) should be able to cover most cases, though with presentation there should probably always be some kind of human eye approach too because WatiN can't automatically detect ugliness yet! (though perhaps there is a program that can)